# web.xml configuration Display tag

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, displaytag

How can I configure a display tag in jsp project?

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/UnhandledException
```

Comment: @parmer, i posted the answer for you..r u still facing the issue..

Comment: If any of the below answer is useful to you. click the accept answer (right symbol).thanks

Comment: could you please paste your code, it might be helpful to me to identify the issue..thanks

Comment: cant .. m new... some constraints on adding the pasting the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For display tag there is not required any configuration in web.xml

display tag is used for pagination sorting in your grid data

there is put only more three jar (1)displaytag-1.2,(2)displaytag-export-poi-1.2,(3)displaytag-portlet-1.2

and write tag lib in your jsp page like:

```
   <%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>
```

your code for griding:

```
        <display:table name="sessionScope.yourListname" pagesize="5" sort="list" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="5">

            <display:column property="var1" title="Title1" sortable="true" />  
            <display:column property="var2" title="Title2" sortable="true" />  
            <display:column property="var3" title="Title3" sortable="true"  />  

        </display:table>
```

for more understanding follow link

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-displaytag-tutorial-sort-pagination-data-displaytag-struts/

Comment: can der by ny prb in my servlet?

Answer (score 0):

### Example Jsp Page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>


<display:table uid="ratingAdjustmentHistoryUID" name="${ratingAdjustmentHistoryForm.ratingAdjustmentHistoryQOList}"
                            requestURI="/ratingAdjustmentHistoryPre.do?method=searchRatingTracker" excludedParams="method"
                            decorator="com.ford.mpl.superg.decorator.RatingAdjustmentHistoryTableDecorator" keepStatus="true" style="width:100%">
                            <%@include file="/jsp/include/displaytag.jsp"%>
                                <display:column property="shipSite" title="RAHSiteCode" sortable="true" />
                                <display:column property="ratingMonth" title="RAHRatingMonth" sortable="true" />
                                <display:column property="prior" title="RAHPrior" sortable="true" />
                                <display:column property="revised" title="RAHRevised" sortable="true" />
                                <display:column property="adjustments" title="RAHAdjustments" sortable="true" />
                                <display:column property="comments" title="RAHComments" sortable="true" />
                                <display:column property="lastUpdated" title="RAHLastUpdated" sortable="true" />
                                <display:column property="lastUpdatedCDSID" title="RAHLastUpdatedCDSID" sortable="true" />
                        </display:table>
```

`RatingAdjustmentHistoryTableDecorator` - It is used for the Decorator

Paste the displaytag.jar file in your location `*YourApplicationName*/Webcontent/WEB-INF/lib/`displaytag-1.2.jar`

[***display tag Overview***](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/)

`display:column` is used to display your column
`property` is used the bean name defined in your java file
`title` is used to show the header of a table
`sortable` is used to sort the individual column or not
`name` is used to get list using the form name
`uid` is a Unique Identifier it is used to store your table as a object
`keepStatus` is used to maintain the status of the table until the session expires

If you have still facing the issue let me know. Thanks.

Comment: <display:table  name="regislist" pagesize="2"  export="True" sort="list"  >
          <display:column  property="fname" title="First Name" sortable="true"  ></display:column>
          <display:column  property="lname" title="Last Name" sortable="true" ></display:column>
          <display:column  property="district" title="District" sortable="true" ></display:column>
          <display:column  property="village" title="Village" sortable="true" ></display:column>   actually i have used bean in my servlet as have put dat bean object in a list.. i was to use dta list here

Comment: wait i will check and let you know that

Comment: Did you closed the display tag </display:table>

Comment: yaa i closed the display tag